# create layout in code and get nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, layout, nullpointerexception

I create my layout in pure code.
It worked and I decided to create another class to reuse my layout.

I add a new class (Designer.java) to reuse my footer and header for other activities.

I pass a context as parameter for other activities.

- rel2MainActivity has 3 children
- relMainActivity is null

I don't understand what's wrong. I must have missed something

**MainActivity.java**

```
RelativeLayout relMainActivity ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...
    Designer design = new Designer();
    design.createDesign(relMainActivity, this);
    // relMainActivity = null in debug

    setContentView(relMainActivity);
    // java.lang.NullPointerException

}
```

**Designer.java**

```
RelativeLayout relHeader, relFooter, relContent;

public void createDesign(RelativeLayout rel2MainActivity, Context context) {

  rel2MainActivity = new RelativeLayout(context);
  // ...
  rel2MainActivity.addView(relHeader, 0);
  rel2MainActivity.addView(relContent, 1);
  rel2MainActivity.addView(relFooter, 2);
  // rel2MainActivity has 3 children in debug 

}
```

Comment: Please post your log cat trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 3 views in `createDesign()` but you are not passing that view back to callee.

So, it is giving null to `relMainActivity`

**Solution :**

Here when you call :

```
    RelativeLayout relHeader, relFooter, relContent;

public RelativeLayout createDesign(RelativeLayout rel2MainActivity, Context context) {

  rel2MainActivity = new RelativeLayout(context);
  // ...
  rel2MainActivity.addView(relHeader, 0);
  rel2MainActivity.addView(relContent, 1);
  rel2MainActivity.addView(relFooter, 2);
  // rel2MainActivity has 3 children in debug 
   // rel2MainActivity view is local to this scope
   // you should return it
   return rel2MainActivity;


}
```

and get it at :

```
RelativeLayout relMainActivity ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...
    Designer design = new Designer();
    relMainActivity = design.createDesign(relMainActivity, this);
    // relMainActivity = null in debug

    setContentView(relMainActivity);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in `createDesign` method directly use `relMainActivity` , or return instance of RelativeLayout and assign it to `relMainActivity` in onCreate just after call of `createDesign` method.

Comment: You're right. It worked thank you. I did that before but I didn't realised that error message was for one subview which was null too :)

Answer (score 1):

You file variable `relMainActivity1` remains null after this line of code

```
design.createDesign(relMainActivity, this);
```

you should change your code to initialize `relMainActivity1` before use it in

```
setContentView(relMainActivity);
```

i.e.

```
  public RelativeLayout createDesign(RelativeLayout rel2MainActivity, Context context) {

      rel2MainActivity = new RelativeLayout(context);
      // ...
      rel2MainActivity.addView(relHeader, 0);
      rel2MainActivity.addView(relContent, 1);
      rel2MainActivity.addView(relFooter, 2);
      // rel2MainActivity has 3 children in debug 

    return rel2MainActivity
    }
```

then use it as

```
relMainActivity= design.createDesign(relMainActivity, this);
setContentView(relMainActivity);
```